# TypeScript Argument Error with strictNullChecks when Checking Nested Object Property

Tags: typescript, strict, strictnullchecks

I am facing an issue with TypeScript's `strictNullChecks` setting. I have a function `handleAction` which expects an argument of type `MyType`.

```js
type MyType = {
  prop: MyEnum;
  // ... other properties
};

enum MyEnum {
  Value1,
  Value2,
  // ... other values
}

async function handleAction(item: MyType) {
  // Function logic here
}
```

Now, I have an object `myRecord` which has a property `nestedItem` that can be `null`.

```js
type MyRecord = {
  nestedItem: MyType | null;
  // ... other properties
};

const myRecord: MyRecord = {
  nestedItem: null, // or some MyType object
  // ... other properties
};
```

I want to check if `nestedItem` exists and if its `prop` is `Value1`. I tried two approaches:

##### Approach 1:

```js
const isCertainCondition =
  myRecord.nestedItem &&
  myRecord.nestedItem.prop === MyEnum.Value1;
  
if (isCertainCondition) {
  await handleAction(myRecord.nestedItem);  // Error here
}
```

##### Approach 2:

```js
if (
  myRecord.nestedItem &&
  myRecord.nestedItem.prop === MyEnum.Value1
) {
  await handleAction(myRecord.nestedItem);  // No error here
}
```

The first approach gives me a TypeScript error:

```
Argument of type 'MyType | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyType'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'MyType'
```

The second approach works without any error.

Why is TypeScript behaving differently between these two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get different results here is [Narrowing | TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)

When you have this type of an example, you use "Truthiness narrowing" to exclude `null`:

```js
async function example2() {
  // 2. this works
  if (myRecord.nestedItem) {
    myRecord.nestedItem
    //       ^? MyType
    await handleAction(myRecord.nestedItem);
    //                          ^? MyType
  }
}
```

Same happens here but you keep the narrowed information in the variable `nestedItem`:

```js
async function example3() {
  const nestedItem = myRecord.nestedItem;

  // 3. this works
  if (nestedItem) {
    nestedItem
    // ^? MyType
    await handleAction(nestedItem);
    //                 ^? MyType
  }
}
```

When you keep the check in the variable `nestedItem` and try to access `myRecord.nestedItem`, you lose the narrowed information because it's only located in the variable `nestedItem`:

```js
async function example4() {
  const nestedItem = myRecord.nestedItem;

  // 4. this does NOT work now because nestedItem and myRecord.nestedItem disconnected from each other
  if (nestedItem) {
    nestedItem
    // ^? MyType
    await handleAction(myRecord.nestedItem);
    //                          ^? MyType | null
  }
}
```

Although you can mitigate this by creating type predicate, e.g. `isDefined`:

```js
const isDefined = Boolean as unknown as <Type>(value: Type) => value is NonNullable<Type>;
```

So instead of truthiness check you can use type predicate:

```js
async function example5() {
  // 5. nestedItem is narrowed down by type predicate
  if (isDefined(myRecord.nestedItem)) {
    await handleAction(myRecord.nestedItem);
    //                          ^? MyType
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have more questions

TypeScript playground with all examples step by step - https://tsplay.dev/m0V4rw